# Cannot get SSIS Script Task to work

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I feel like I am missing some configuration or something, because I have followed tons of tutorials online, but cannot get any examples of a script task to work.  I cannot debug the error either because I am not a C# developer.

Currently, I am simply checking if a file exists in a directory:

1) `User::gvLastMonthImportFile` is string (read-only) & `User::gvLastMonthImportFileExists` is Boolean (read-write)

2) Added `using System.IO;` to my namespaces

3)

```
string fullPath = Dts.Variables["User::gvLastMonthImportFile"].Value.ToString();
Dts.Variables["User::gvLastMonthImportFileExists"].Value = File.Exists(fullPath);
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;`
```

ERROR:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: That's not your error.  That's a stack trace.   There must be more to the error message than that.

Comment: How do I get the error?

Comment: If I was a gambling man (I'm not) I would say you don't have permission on the folder. But as Tab Alleman noted there is more to the error message that you are showing us.

Comment: Is the error in development mode (within the ide) or after deployment. If the former and you have sql2012 you can step through your code while it is debugging.

Comment: Please post your complete list of your namespaces.

Comment: using System;
  using System.Data;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.IO;

Comment: I am also running in debug as my own local user, so I should have permission to this folder.  In fact, this is the same folder from which I am importing data files, so I know I have some permission.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that `fullPath` is a valid path. I suggest you use a for each file loop instead of a script task to do this.

Comment: If I copy the rendered path from the variables into my file explorer, it opens the file.  it is a shared network drive though, but my personal user account has access and I am running in debug using my local user profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this recently and it was because I had not added the variables to the script.

You have to explicitly add ReadOnlyVariables/ReadWriteVariables to the script task for it to have any access to them by double-clicking the script task in the designer, selecting 'Script' on the right-hand side of the dialog and then clicking the ReadOnlyVariables/ReadWriteVariables drop down.

I know this reply is late but this caused me a lot of grief and hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: This was the issue for me, would never have figured that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I want to had a screenshot to help debug these cases :
After closing the cryptic error prompt, watch into your debug output, there will be a short yet more useful error message :
[image]

Comment: ah merci pour ca!

Answer (score 0):

Steps to run

1. adding 2 lines code in the script.

   ```
   Messagebox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::gvLastMonthImportFile"].Value.ToString());
   Messagebox.Show(File.Exists(fullPath).Value.ToString());
   ```
2. save and close the script, OK script task.
3. right click script task, execute the task.
4. when task is executing, the message will pop up. Please verify the data.

[image: Is there any warning in the right hand side of script window?]

[image]

Comment: I added these lines, but an "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" before it will even execute the script.  If I "Close" that trace message, it fails the task.  No outputs.

Comment: Where did you run the code? in the script window? You must close it and execute the script task.

Comment: No.  I saved, clicked OK, and executed the task.  At this point, I am wondering if it's some kind of DLL or library I am missing?

Comment: I just added an image, is there any warning/error in your right hand side of script window?

Comment: There are no warnings and I see the same references you have.  Not sure if this means anything, but above `public void Main()` it says "0 references"

Comment: I added another image. No idea what "0 references" is.

Comment: Script Tasks should be configured to run out-of-the-box right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143810/discussion-between-wendy-and-pablo-boswell).

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem and was stuck for a couple of hours. Then I found my problem. Variables are case-sensitive and I had misspelled one of them.